# Is there a way to install OpenJDK Java in Amazon Linux 2023?

Tags: java, centos7, java-11, amazon-linux-2023

In the process of trying out a switch to Amazon Linux 2023 from Centos7 and I am trying to understand my options for Java.

I am currenly running Java 11 openjdk in Centos7. Ideally I'd like to match my old java version as closely as possible. In the past we've had bugs come up due to errantly using Oracle java instead of OpenJDK. So what I really want is OpenJDK, but it's not clear if anyone even builds OpenJDK for AL2023 yet (or ever will?).

The latest amazon corretto java rpm from `java-11-amazon-corretto` has version 11.0.20+9-1.amzn2023, which is quite close, but I'd like to minimize my changes if possible.

When I do a `dnf search openjdk`  I don't get any hits:

```
[ec2-user@blah ~]$ dnf search openjdk
Amazon Linux 2023 repository                                                         17 MB/s |  14 MB     00:00
Amazon Linux 2023 Kernel Livepatch repository                                       496 kB/s | 159 kB     00:00
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Mon Sep 11 20:47:56 2023.
No matches found.
```

I understand that AL2023 is Fedora-based, but also it doesn't seem like AL2023 is compatible with Fedora packages either (as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/relationship-to-fedora.html)

So... is there an openjdk alternative to Amazon Corretto Java? What repo would provide that? If not, is that something that is likely to get created in the future?

Comment: What's the problem with installing 11.0.20+9-1.amzn2023? It is of course Java11 and considering security threats in the future, we can always expect newer minor versions of it. This is a normal process.

Comment: I don't know what problems may arise from changing Java distribution but given that I'm already changing to Amazon Linux 2023, I'd like to minimize the changes I am making. After validating that my app performs consistently on the new operating system, then I can consider changing Java. That said, there's no business need to change java distribution whereas Centos7 is reaching EOL which isn't acceptable.

Comment: The changes for Corretto are fairly minimal and are partly around just making sure that OpenJDK works nicely with Amazon Linux(s). It's natural to be cautious, but look at the changes yourself to see if there's anything scary: [Change Log for Amazon Corretto 11](https://github.com/corretto/corretto-11/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: No such thing as "OpenJDK" that you can install, no such thing as "Java 11 openjdk". [*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) is an open-source project providing an implementation of the Java specification, but this project produces only source code, not binaries/installers. Several vendors provide JDK binaries/installers, and most of these are built largely upon the codebase provided by OpenJDK. These vendors include Azul Systems, Adoptium, Amazon, Microsoft, SAP, IBM, Red Hat, BellSoft, and more. …

Comment: …  *Corretto* is the JDK product from Amazon, built entirely from the OpenJDK source code except for occasional changes by Amazon staff that they then donate back to the OpenJDK project.

Comment: Regarding "errantly using Oracle java instead of OpenJDK" — For multiple years now, Oracle has based their *Oracle JDK* product directly on the OpenJDK source code, just as Amazon does with *Corretto*. Like Amazon, Oracle reserve the right to to make urgent fixes as needed for paying customers, and later donate those back to the OpenJDK codebase.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm starting to get it. What I was thought was the 'openjdk' distribution of Java in centos7 was actually just the one bundled with the operating system, which was most likely maintained by Redhat/Centos in a similar fashion to oracle-jdk or corretto-jdk (i.e. a layer on top of openjdk). The package in question was `java-11-openjdk-devel`, and my confusion comes partly from the nondescript package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corretto *is* a build of OpenJDK. OpenJDK is source code that can be compiled into binaries by anyone. So if you want to install OpenJDK in Amazon Linux 2023, Corretto is a good choice.

Actually, Corretto identifies itself as OpenJDK:

```
$ sudo dnf install java-21-amazon-corretto
...
$ java --version
openjdk 21.0.1 2023-10-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-21.0.1.12.1 (build 21.0.1+12-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-21.0.1.12.1 (build 21.0.1+12-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

See also: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/java.html

> Corretto is a build of the Open Java Development Kit (OpenJDK) with long-term support from Amazon.

---

Historically, AL 2023 has provided extra OpenJDK packages, but they have been removed with release 2022.0.20220810:

> In this release, we have removed the remaining openjdk packages, as we have shifted Amazon Linux 2022 to use Amazon Corretto as the JVM in the distribution.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/release-notes/relnotes-2022.0.20220810.html

---

(The comments on the questions already contain lots of helpful information. Adding this answer anyway as a summary with references for future visitors.)